# d3 doesn't append namespace attributes to svg element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I wonder why D3.js doesn't add the namespace attributes to the SVG element.

```
d3.ns.prefix.ex = 'http://example.com/';
var chart = d3.select('#chart').append('svg:svg');
```

I think the output should something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ex="http://example.com/">
```

Actually its just

```
<svg>
```

See this fiddle for a complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/7kWDK/

Comment: I'm wondering how you solved the problem. I've been struggling with a similar problem. You can see the result with a working example in the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929742/how-to-embed-svg-styling-with-javascript

Comment: You have to add the attribute manually (but you should add the namespace to `d3.ns.prefix` too): https://github.com/gopeter/semantic-diagrams/blob/ad630ba1566bbaba622e317732d9d90a2f281fab/static/js/app.js#L132

Comment: @Slevin: what have been your exact code for namespace injection and use so the file is valid and downloadable ? I'am struggling with this too http://jsfiddle.net/99dex43s/5/

Comment: Did you seen the link above your comment? Check line 132, that's all :)

Comment: Slevin: Cool ! Please add this as the valid solution and validate it so it's more visible.

Comment: @Selvin: I tried to apply your approach but without success so far http://jsfiddle.net/99dex43s/21/ , the resulting svg is still invalid due to each custom attributes. The xml code seems ok as far as I understand (see it via `$head -c 750 ./test.svg` ). But doesn't pass the validator. I surely miss something in your way to do it. Could you provide a working jsfiddle ?

Comment: Note: Selvin's Jquery `$('svg').attr('xmlns:my_ns', 'http://example.com/'); ` solution is a **practical solution** (svg do to display in browsers), not a strict solution (code stays invalid). But is does work ! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

namespace attributes are only relevant when documents are served as some XML mime type e.g. image/svg+xml.

namespaces don't do anything in html markup such as jsfiddle so d3 doesn't need to create them.

If you want namespaces then you could add the attributes manually in html or alternatively switch to xhtml where the attributes will be automatically created.

Comment: But I want to save the generated SVG, so I need the attributes.

Comment: You could add them manually or alternatively switch to xhtml rather than html

Comment: When using an XHTML doctype D3.js would add the namespace attributes??

Comment: No, it would be automatically present based on the fact that its creating elements in the SVG namespace.

Comment: OK, but thats not the point. The SVG should be exported as file. I want to include the SVG code in HTML as preview for the user, but the SVG file itself should be a valid document with namespace attributes. So I'm going to add them manually. But why does D3 provide functions to declare namespaces? Whats the point about `d3.ns.prefix`? Just to let D3 know I'm using namespace (even if D3 does not really matter?). I'm confused.

Comment: I thought it was the point, in xhtml the attributes will be present automatically. Neither D3 or you would need to do anything. D3 works with XML documents e.g. svg or xhtml as well as html so it provides functions that are needed for xml documents.

Comment: Still confusing (for beginners)

Comment: @RobertLongson: In practice, what do you means by "switch to xhtml" , how to do it ?

Comment: Per the first line in the answer.