# How to embed SVG styling with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to embed a CSS styling into a SVG content (like [in this example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StyleElementExample)) using JavaScript. The SVG itself is embedded into a HTML5 file. The purpose of style embedding is to save a SVG online created content into a standalone *.svg file.

Here is the first tested content: http://jsfiddle.net/3L8a2oxy/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SVG embedded styling</title>
</head>

<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs></defs>
        <circle  cx="50" cy="50"  r="25"/>
    </svg>

    <script>
        var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
        var defs = svg.getElementsByTagName('defs')[0];
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        defs.appendChild(style);
        style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

        var node = document.createTextNode('<![CDATA[circle { fill: red; }]]>');
        style.appendChild(node);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In that example styling doesn't work:

[image]

and Firefox (v 34.0.5) gives the error:

> Selector expected. Rulset ignore due to bad selector.

However, if you make a separate html file with this code, save it, and reopen in a browser, the styling can be seen, i.e. it is parsed by browser correctly.

If one changes the style code as to:

```
var node = document.createTextNode('circle { fill: red; }');
```

[image]

then styling works online with no errors (http://jsfiddle.net/8grf344g/). But it's not what the specifications told us to do. I can save the SVG part into a file in then open it in the browser, and it appears to be styled correctly, but I'm not sure how it will behave in other applications.

So, the question is in the subject.

PS. There is another issue for which I haven't found any solution yet. If you try to merge style data with style tag as follows:

```
var node = document.createTextNode('<style type=\'text/css\'><![CDATA[circle { fill: red; }]]></style>');
defs.appendChild(node);
```

then to goes into the document encoded:

```
&lt;style type='text/css'&gt;&lt;![CDATA[circle { fill: red; }]]&gt;&lt;/style&gt;
```

I know it happens for the inner content of html elements, but why it doesn't happen in the above first case?

**P.S.** Since the answers to the subject kindly provided by the community point to a right direction, but don't give a working example, I put one to jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/26wfwa12/1/). Feel free to use it and comment.

Comment: _"why it doesn't happen in the above first case?"_ Why doesn't what happen in what first case?

Comment: @JLRish, good question.
In the first case: `document.createTextNode('<![...` the '<' symbol will be **not** encoded as `&gt` in the saved page. 
In the seconde case: `document.createTextNode('<style...` the '<' symbol will be encode as `&gt` in the saved page.

Comment: This is happening because in HTML (as opposed to XHTML), text content isn't escaped inside `<style>` or `<script>` elements. It is encoded inside any other type of element. So when you added text with `<>`s to `defs`, the text was escaped, but the text you added to the `style` element was not. Observe: http://jsfiddle.net/0zqfhmpr/3/

Comment: Well, based on answers of @JLRishe and **Robert Longson**, I've created an an example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26wfwa12/1/)) where the SVG can be saved as a file (an external library used).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've two main bugs. Firstly, you need to create the style element in the SVG namespace i.e.

```
var style = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'style');
```

Secondly you can't use `<![CDATA[` in html it's an xhtml only thing so you want

```
var node = document.createTextNode('circle { fill: red; }');
```

Finally (and this bit is optional), the text/css attribute can be omitted if you wish. All of which [gives you this](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/3L8a2oxy/2/)

The specifications certainly **do not** tell you to use `<![CDATA[` with html, but they do tell you to use it with xhtml and xml and SVG at one time was an xml only language. If you intend to have standalone svg files (which will be served as image/svg+xml) then you may need to put the `<![CDATA[` back in.

Comment: Thanks, @Robert. For the first 'bug' I don't see any difference in the content produced by the code.
The the CDATA can't be included into SVG embedded into HTML, but it must be included into SVG file if there is an embedded styling. Is it correct? Then, one needs to add CDATA on-fly when saving SVG content into a file?

Comment: You will if you examine the content's namespace.

Comment: In practice the first 'bug' won't make much of a difference apart from the style element itself being in the svg namespace, the styles will still be applied the same.

Comment: It will if you're using Batik or you try to refer to external script content via xlink:href. Otherwise you're right an html script element will work pretty much the same as an SVG one.